# Garbage collection + memory paging

Tags: garbage-collection, operating-system, jvm

I am trying to understand the `collaboration` between `GC` inside `JVM` and the memory paging.  I have a `linux` box which has `4GB RAM` and allocated `1.2GB for JVM`. If I run an application which requires heavy memory, I am wondering when the memory paging happens and when it actually `throws` out of memory error.  when an object is created, it is created on the heap and will be garbage-collected if it is not used or alive if it is used by an application.

So my question is when does the OS start memory paging for `JVM` and what happens to the live object that is paged by `OS`?

And also if the OS pages live java objects, how does it prioritize which object should be paged first?  does it page the object that occupies most of memory?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is : the JVM has absolutely no way of knowing that the OS swaps the heap, or from preventing it from swapping.

To be more precise, you may turn on JVM flags to prevent swapping (`-XX:+UseLargePages`), but if the OS runs out of large pages, it will revert to regular swapping. Also, any GC cycle will force every page to be fetched into RAM so that it can be inspected. So basically, swapping + Full GC = you are going to run into a hell of a Stop-The-World.

G1 will have a slightly different behaviour, since it will collect first the memory regions that are filled with dead objects, but it will still take more time due to page faults.

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks. If paging is handled by OS, why does OutOfMemory happens?

Comment: Well, an OutOfMemoryError means that the heap (those 1.2GB) is not big enough to store every objects you created, it is not directly linked to paging.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Memory Paging is handled by the underlying OS and not by the JVM.

If you meant de-fragmentation, then yes JVM does it for you. [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) gives more insight on how it is handled by the Garbage Collector which transfers long-lived objects to different generations and thus de-fragments on the go. This obviously affects which objects are paged out/not. But this is the max indirect-control what you have (by prolonging or shortening the life of the object)

And as per the memory heap, it is purely when there is no more space left.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that OS handles the paging and GC handles the memory management by moving objects from YG to OG. My question is that when the memory paging happens in OS side and how is the paged object handled between OS and JVM?

Comment: For the OS, JVM process is like any other process with no special access. So when JVM wants to access an object which is currently in say Virtual memory, based on demand the OS transfers it back from virtual memory and is made available. And in mean time, OS might transfer some object content to virtual memory. If you want to know when, then it happens when the JVM requests OS to get the object lying at an address, based on which OS gets the content and pages out something else